# How can i export a var with specific class

Tags: godot

I want to export a `HealthComponent`

```
extends Node2D
class_name HealthComponent
```

in `HitComponent` node I tried 2 ways:

```
export var HealthComponent: Node2D
```

and

```
export var HealthComponent: HealthComponent
```

and it gives me this error:
[image: an error]

note: my version is `v3.5.2.stable`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
export(NodePath) var HealthComponentPath

onready var HealthComponent = get_node(HealthComponentPath)
```

Here is [Godot 3.5 `export` documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html). It says:

> An exported variable must be initialized to a constant expression or
> have an export hint in the form of an argument to the export keyword
> (see the Examples section below).

What it means is you can use either form, initializing with a constant expression

```
export var <Name> = <constant expr.>
```

or using `export(<RecourceType>)` syntax.
But both ways Godot 3 requires variable to be of a built-in or native
[resource type](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_resource.html), and `Node2D` is not.

> # If the exported value assigns a constant or constant expression, the type will be inferred and used in the editor.
>
> export var number = 5
>
> # Export can take a basic data type as an argument, which will be used in the editor.
>
> export(int) var number
>
> # Export can also take a resource type to use as a hint.
>
> ...

[Godot 4](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html) added possibility to do that directly, but old syntax like this is also supported there.

> Since Godot 4.0, nodes can be directly exported as properties in a script without having to use NodePaths. ... Exporting NodePaths like in Godot 3.x is still possible.